# Forward Hero Card from Skype Chatbot with functional buttons (or deeplinking chatbot and passing a reference)

Tags: botframework, chatbot, skypedeveloper

Is there a way to create a hero card that has buttons that keep working when it is forwarded to another user?

We want to build a chatbot that enables you to share things with someone else.  So first you talk to the chatbot (mainly via buttons) to setup a thing and then you forward that to one of your contacts so that they can participate. With Facebook Messenger we can directly call a share action that pops up the share dialog with which the user can forward a card to a contact. Using a `m.me/123?ref=456` URL in a button of the card the receiver can open a conversation with the chatbot in the correct context. I managed to do something similar for Telegram.

I try to replicate this with other services. With Skype there is no way to explicitly call the share action, but I can write a message "Please forward the next card to the user you want to share this with:" [and then I display that card]. Now I give that card a button with a `postBack` action that should open the correct context, but that button seems to be non functional. When tapping it no post back is sent to the chatbot.

Is there a way to implement something like what I described for Facebook Messenger with Skype? Or is there a way to deep link to a chatbot passing some reference?

(I'd rather have the later for a second use case anyway, where a user puts a share button on their website that then opens Skype in a conversation with the chatbot, passing the reference. I have that for Messenger and Telegram.)

**Edit:** What I would like to do would basically be the following. I use nodejs, but only the `ChatConnector` class and not the `UniversalBot` class.

```
connector.send([
    {
        type: 'message',
        address,
        textFomrat: 'plain',
        text: 'Forward the next message to people you want to share THING with:',
    },
    {
        type: 'message',
        address,
        attachments: [{
            contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero',
            content: {
                title: name,
                images: [{
                    url: image_url
                }],
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'postBack',
                    title: 'Chat with this bot about THING',
                    value: 'open:' + thing_id,
                }]
            }
        }],
    }
], callback);
```

Comment: I implemented a poc of something similar to this in the past couple days: https://github.com/matthidinger/ContosoScubaBot/blob/master/Services/ReservationSubscriptionService.cs  If an ms teams user sends a /subscribe message to the bot, they will receive notifications when a webchat user finishes making a reservation.  They can click a link that opens a webchat, where all messages are proxied to the user who just made the reservation. This uses the v4 sdk, but a similar thing can be done in v3 without much effort.

Comment: But I don't want a webchat, I want them to use their Skype client (on the phone) with their Skype login. Also its an interaction between 2 users her. User A wants to share something with user B. Something with which user B will interact with. So I thought user A just forwards a card to user B manually (because there is no share function like Facebook Messenger has), but then the card is dysfunctional when user B receives it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're sending cards to the other user, but here's an example in .net where the buttons sent will function as expected for the other user:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ConnectorEx;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CardsBot
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SendToUserDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _cachedConversationReferences = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>();
        private const string HelpString = "Enter 'Send Card' to send a card to another user. 'Send Message' to send a json message to another user.  Or 'List Users' to see who is ready to receive messages.";

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;

            string upperText = message.Text.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper();
            if (upperText == "SENDCARD")
            {
                IFormDialog<SendCardForm> form = new FormDialog<SendCardForm>(new SendCardForm(), SendCardForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                context.Call(form, AfterSendCardComplete);
            }
            else if (upperText == "SENDMESSAGE")
            {
                IFormDialog<SendMessageForm> form = new FormDialog<SendMessageForm>(new SendMessageForm(), SendMessageForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                context.Call(form, AfterSendMessageFormComplete);
            }
            else if (upperText == "LISTUSERS")
            {
                var names = String.Join(", ", _cachedConversationReferences.Keys);
                await context.PostAsync($"Users : {names}");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!context.UserData.ContainsKey("name"))
                {
                    var getNamePrompt = new PromptDialog.PromptString("What is your name?", "Please enter your name.", 3);
                    context.Call(getNamePrompt, AfterNamePrompt);
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"You said: {message.Text} ({HelpString})");
                    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
                }
            }
        }
        private async Task AfterSendMessageFormComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SendMessageForm> result)
        {
            var sendMessageForm = await result;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendMessageForm.RecipientName))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("A recipient name was not provided.  Cannot send the message to nobody.");
            }
            else
            {
                ConversationReference conversation = null;
                if (_cachedConversationReferences.TryGetValue(sendMessageForm.RecipientName, out conversation))
                {
                    var originalReply = conversation.GetPostToBotMessage().CreateReply();
                    var replyMessage = GetMessage(originalReply, sendMessageForm.MessageJson);

                    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(originalReply.ServiceUrl));
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);

                    await context.PostAsync($"Message was sent to {sendMessageForm.RecipientName} on {replyMessage.ChannelId} channel.");
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"No recipient found matching the name {sendMessageForm.RecipientName}");
                }
            }
        }
        private async Task AfterNamePrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            var name = await result;
            context.UserData.SetValue("name", name);
            await context.PostAsync($"Thanks.  What would you like to do now {name}? {HelpString}");

            var conversationReference = context.Activity.ToConversationReference();
            _cachedConversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(name, conversationReference, (oldVal, newVal) => conversationReference);
        }

        public Activity GetMessage(Activity originalReply, string messageJson)
        {
            var reply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(messageJson);
            reply.ChannelId = originalReply.ChannelId;
            reply.Timestamp = originalReply.Timestamp;
            reply.From = originalReply.From;
            reply.Conversation = originalReply.Conversation;
            reply.Recipient = originalReply.Recipient;
            reply.Id = originalReply.Id;
            reply.ReplyToId = originalReply.ReplyToId;
            reply.ServiceUrl = originalReply.ServiceUrl;

            return reply;
        }

        private async Task AfterSendCardComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SendCardForm> result)
        {
            var SendCardForm = await result;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SendCardForm.RecipientName))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("A recipient name was not provided.  Cannot send a card to nobody.");
            }
            else
            {
                ConversationReference conversation = null;
                if (_cachedConversationReferences.TryGetValue(SendCardForm.RecipientName, out conversation))
                {
                    var reply = conversation.GetPostToBotMessage().CreateReply();
                    reply.Attachments.Add(GetCard(SendCardForm.Text, SendCardForm.Buttons.Value));

                    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(reply.ServiceUrl));
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"No recipient found matching the name {SendCardForm.RecipientName}");
                }
            }
        }

        public Attachment GetCard(string text, int numberOfButtons)
        {
            var card = new HeroCard(text);
            card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>(GetCardActions(numberOfButtons));
            return card.ToAttachment();
        }

        private IEnumerable<CardAction> GetCardActions(int numberOfButtons)
        {
            for (int counter = 1; counter < numberOfButtons; counter++)
            {
                yield return new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = $"button{counter}",
                    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                    Value = $"button{counter}"
                };
            }
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SendMessageForm
    {
        [Prompt("Who would you like to send this message to (enter the name of the recipient)?")]
        public string RecipientName { get; set; }
        [Prompt("Paste in the .json of the message you would like to Send.")]
        public string MessageJson { get; set; }

        public static IForm<SendMessageForm> BuildForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<SendMessageForm>()
                            .AddRemainingFields()
                            .Confirm("Is this information correct?{*}")
                            .Build();
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class SendCardForm
    {
        [Prompt("What would you like for the card text?")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Prompt("How many buttons?")]
        public int? Buttons { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Who would you like to send the card to?")]
        public string RecipientName { get; set; }

        public static IForm<SendCardForm> BuildForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<SendCardForm>()
                            .AddRemainingFields()
                            .Confirm("Is this information correct?{*}")
                            .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See the update for how I'd like to do it. Ah, so you mean using `imBack` I could make it work? Have to try that. Note that I'd like that the tap of the button doesn't send any text to the chat, especially not to the user that forwarded the message.

Comment: Ok, I tried `imBack`. That sends the message to the person who shared the card, *NOT* to the bot. So that doesn't work either.

Comment: The code i shared in this answer works as expected. If you have some other code, please share it and i'll review.

Comment: Look at the code I added to the question. The postBack is never received by the bot if a user taps the button in the card if the card was forwarded. And if postBack is changed to imBack the value is sent to the person that shared the card, NOT to the bot.

Comment: What code are you using to 'share the card'?  I'll need enough information/code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: How are you constructing the connector?  What is the value for address? What is the value of thing_id?

Comment: What is any of that relevant for? Let's say `thing_id` is 123. address is the address of the user that initiated this exchange. So far this all does work. What do you mean with "What code are you using to 'share the card'?" You can't do that with BotFramework/Skype. You cant initiate a share dialog. That's why I do it like that. I tell the user to forward the card manually. connector is created like this: `connector = new BotBuilder.ChatConnector({appId: ..., appPassword: ...});` I don't use `UniversalBot` because I don't need the features it provides. It's just unnecessary craft for me.

Comment: What doesn't work is when the person that receives the forwarded card taps a button of the card.

Comment: Without a complete example demonstrating the issue you are seeing, I'm unable to determine what is going wrong.  I understand the requirements, and provided a way to do this (in c#, not knowing you were using node).  Without seeing your code, I have no idea why it is failing when the person receives the forwarded card.

Comment: I don't know what else you need? About your code: where do you fill `_cachedConversationReferences`? Where do you get a `ConversationReference` from? The chatbot never saw the final recipient of the card! That's the point of sharing stuff. To share something with a user that never saw that thing (the chatbot in a certain context) before.
Messenger has a way to trigger a share dialog which opens the users contact list and lets the user send a card to one of their contacts. Skype has no such feature, thus I have to instruct the user to forward the card manually.

Comment: In order to demonstrate the issue, start a conversation with the Doctor Who bot (https://join.skype.com/bot/943933b0-d119-46de-932d-71f5042bb99e) and then forward the first card you get to another user (or yourself). The recipient of the forwarded card has now a dysfunctional card.

Comment: Forward the card?  How exactly are you doing that in the skype client?

Comment: I tell the user to do it. There is a forward icon beside the card. Tap it, select the user to forward it, done.